# Initialize postgresql 11 with custom datadir on fedora 31

Tags: linux, fedora, systemd, postgresql, systemd-unit

According to what I learn so far, I should create a new systemd unit file with the provided script. Then I should initialize the datadir. These are the commands I ran:

```
$ sudo /usr/sbin/postgresql-new-systemd-unit --datadir /opt/data/pgsql/data --unit postgresql@custom
 * The 'postgresql@custom.service' configured in '/etc/systemd/system/postgresql@custom.service.d' directory.

$ sudo /usr/bin/postgresql-setup --initdb --unit postgresql@custom
FATAL: no db datadir (PGDATA) configured for 'postgresql@custom.service' unit
```

The folder `/etc/systemd/system/postgresql@custom.service.d/` contains only 1 file:

```
$ sudo ls /etc/systemd/system/postgresql@custom.service.d/
30-postgresql-setup.conf

$ sudo cat /etc/systemd/system/postgresql@custom.service.d/30-postgresql-setup.conf
[Service]
Environment=PGDATA=/opt/data/pgsql/data
```

What is wrong with my procedure? What is the correct way?

Please advice.